# problema de código de windows a mac

Tags: c#, windows, macos

recientemente me he migrado a sistema operativo macOS pero al copiar un repositorio de git hub a "visual studio para Mac" el cual ha sido codificado en windows "visual studio", el código que funcionaba bien en windows cuando lo ejecutabas en debug o una prueba, ahora en Mac no se ejecuta bien y te da errores.

no consigo percibir por que pasa eso.

**Código**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CalculoPesetas
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            /*
            -progama que calcula una cantidad en pesetas ¿980908
            */

            Double Euros = new Double();
            Double Pesetas = new Double();
            Double Cambio = new Double();

            Console.WriteLine("Por favor introduce la cantidad para cambiar: ");

            Euros = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (Euros > 0)
            {
                Pesetas = 166.386;

                Cambio = Euros * Pesetas;

                Console.WriteLine("Usted tiene " + Cambio + "pesetas");

                Console.WriteLine("Presiona Cualquier Tecla para acabar ......");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("el valor introducido no es valido, por favor asegurese que es mayor que 0");
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Podría ayudarme.

Comment: ¿Que tipo de proyecto es .Net Core o .Net Framework ?

Comment: no te se decir son programas sencillos de consola. me podrías explicar cual es la diferencia ???

Comment: Alli cree una respuesta aclarando un poco

Comment: y si añades los errores para saber que es lo que pudiera estar pasando?

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio para Mac, solo corre codigo de .Net core / .Net Standard ,

En cambio Windows Corre .Net Full Framework y .Net core / .Net Standard; es decir todos los mencionados.

**.Net Full Framework**

> Es la alternativa que veníamos usando hasta el día de hoy en el
>   desarrollo de nuestras aplicaciones, también conocida como Full
>   Framework en la actualidad. Se distribuye con el sistema operativo (es
>   lo que estamos acostumbrados hasta el día de hoy, para correr una
>   aplicación .NET debíamos tener la versión correspondiente del
>   Framework instalada en el equipo.

https://diegobersano.com.ar/2017/05/30/net-standard-una-libreria-para-dominarlos-a-todos/

**Net Standard**

> Estándar de .NET es un conjunto de APIs que todas las plataformas .NET
>   tienen que implementar. Esto unifica las plataformas .NET y previene
>   la fragmentación futura.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

**.Net Core**

> NET Core es una implementación de código abierto, modular,
>   multiplataforma y de código abierto de .NET Standard. Contiene muchas
>   de las mismas API que .NET Framework (pero .NET Core es un conjunto
>   más pequeño)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/net-core-and-open-source

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: vale ya lo entendí probablemente mi código en windows se haya hecho con .net framework, y el Mac al correr solo .net core pues aparece el problema.

Comment: podría solucionarlo de alguna manera ??? instalando el framework o algo parecido ???

Comment: En tal caso deberías pensar en una migración con net Standard. 
Fijate aqui la tabla de compatibilidades.(Es decir re programar algunas cosas)
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard.

Comment: De hecho, net core 2 no soporta proyectos del tipo windows forms (se supone que con net core 3 si).
Si me das algunos detalles del proyecto podría ir viendo por donde viene la mano.

Comment: si mira se trata de un pequeño programa de consola que te pide un valor en euros y te lo pasa a pesetas son las primeras practicas.

Comment: Si, podes hacerlo directamente, Net Core 2 si soport este tipo de applicaciones.
Desde la Mac deberías crear una nueva solución con net core 2, del tipo consola, luego vas agregando los archivos de tu otra solución uno a uno, y allí vas viendo en que te da error y lo arreglas.

Comment: abajo te pongo el código, el programa cuando lo ejecutas de dice en el 'readline()' que ese objeto no puede ser nulo. cuando no me ha dejado poner ningún valor

Comment: @andresribeiro esta línea: "Euros = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());" separala en dos línas: "var strEuros = Console.ReadLine();" y "Euros = Double.Parse(strEuros );" de esa forma, antes de hacer el "Double.Parse(strEuros )" puedes verificar si el valor de strEuros no es null.